How to fix loose stair nosing?
The nosing at the very top of our stairs has come loose, most likely when we had a new hot water tank installed, and the weight of the replacement tank and/or one of the workers stepped a little too heavily on the nosing. Is this a simple fix with adhesive? Does it have to be removed entirely to apply if so? Thank you.


Drill pilot holes in the nosing exactly where the stringers are, and then use a countersink bit ($2). Use 2 - 2" minimum wood screws to attach to the stringers. You can leave it like that with the screw heads flush with the surface. Or tighten the screws a little more, about 2-3mm under the surface, then use wood filler. Sand. Apply polyurethane if desired. Done.

Thank you. Alternatively, would you advise against using something like LePage PL Construction Adhesive instead of drilling/screws? I don't see any by the contractor when we had the floors redone a few years ago.

You could use construction adhesive, something like Liquid Nails. It might work until it gets hit again. But nothing will be as strong as mechanical fasteners

Makes sense, cheers.
